# Insert a number as intiger to mongodb in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**ERROR**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning : MongoError: $multiply only supports numeric types, not string
```

problem is i have took the sum of the products in the cart. but the price is as string format...the parse Int not working
is there any way to insert as number to the database

---

**ADD PRODUCT CODE**

```
 addProduct: (product, callback) => {
        db.get().collection('product').insertOne(product).then((data) => {
            callback(data.ops[0]._id)
        })

    }
```

---

**TO FIND THE SUM AND RETURN **

```js
getTotalAmount:(userId)=>{
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let total = await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).aggregate([
            {
                $match: { user: objectId(userId) }
            },
            {
                $unwind: '$products'
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    item: '$products.item',
                    quantity: '$products.quantity'
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION,
                    localField: 'item',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'product'

                }
            }
            ,
            {
                $project: {
                    item: 1, quantity: 1, product: { $arrayElemAt: ['$product', 0] }
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                $group:{
                    _id:null,
                    total:{$sum:{$multiply:['$quantity','$product.price']}}
                }
            }

        ]).toArray()
        console.log(total[0].total);
        resolve(total)
    })
```

---

Comment: The real issue seems to be this - "the parse Int not working". Please provide an example of this issue.

Comment: There is no parseInt i have used...the form contains both string and number elements...but all of the items are stored as strings...is there parseInt needed ..if Yes where should i include...iam currently pushing all the elements in the product directly to the database

Comment: It sounds like you should consider sending the relevant properties already as numbers, or transform the data in the backend just before inserting to the DB. The first option should be better. If the data is numeric why is it being sent as string in the first place?

Comment: I am currently pushing the whole as a object...so please tell me how to send as intiger to DB

Comment: Please change the question then. Make it about the actual change you want to make. Include just the relevant information - a sample of the product object for example.